# How do I format the output of nmap to display on conky?

Tags: networking, conky, nmap

I want to add to the network section of conky a list of all hosts and ips for my network.

However I do not know how to format the output in a way I like.

I want

- Live Hosts However this is on the bottom line of `nmap`'s output)
- host (ip)
- host (ip)
- and on and on...

I think there should be a max of 7 on my network. How can I do this? The output of `nmap -sP 192.168.1.0/24` looks nothing like what I want though it does have all the parts, just in the wrong order.

Comment: Can someone explain `awk` and/or `grep` to the OP?

Comment: @ObsessiveFOSS You're someone! :)

Comment: @WolfLarson Please **edit your question** to add the current output, and the desired output. We'll be able to help more then.

Comment: @SirCharlo What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with the text output of `namp`, then yeah, I would reccomend looking into using `grep` and/or `awk` to shape the output. If you just want something pretty to look at, install and use `zenmap`.

`sudo apt-get install zenmap`

Then run:

`sudo zenmap`

It's a very nice graphical overlay for `nmap` and you can manipulate and navigate the map results rather nicely.